# puppeteer text box with no id

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to use Puppeteer to enter a value in an input field. Ive done it for most of a web page but having a real problem with a specific field that doesn't have an id or a good label.

here is the inspect elements

```
<div class="retype-security-code"><input type="text" class="form-text mask-cvv-4" aria-label="Security code" placeholder="CVV2" value=""><img src="https://c1.neweggimages.com/WebResource/Themes/Nest/images/cvv2_sm.gif" alt="cvv2"></div>

<input type="text" class="form-text mask-cvv-4" aria-label="Security code" placeholder="CVV2" value="">
```

[image of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNYIo.png)

here is some code that Ive been playing with

```
    while (true) {

    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('#cvv2Code' , {timeout: 500})
        await page.type('#cvv2Code', config.cv2)
        break
    } 
    catch (err) {}

    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('#creditCardCVV2' , {timeout: 500})
        await page.type('#creditCardCVV2', config.cv2)
        break
    } 
    catch (err) {}

    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('#app > div > section > div > div > form > div.row-inner > div.row-body > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.checkout-step-body > div.checkout-step-done > div.card > div.retype-security-code > input' , {timeout: 500})
        await page.focus('#app > div > section > div > div > form > div.row-inner > div.row-body > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.checkout-step-body > div.checkout-step-done > div.card > div.retype-security-code > input')
        await page.keyboard.type('###')
        break
    } 
    catch (err) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `#cvv2Code` and `#creditCardCVV2` as selectors when they are *not* in your html code, nor in the picture?

This class `form-text mask-cvv-4` seems like a reasonable option for the field:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.form-text.mask-cvv-4');
```

---

Those selectors in the last try block are too long, that's unmaintainable and hard to read, avoid writing such selectors.

Also, please add all relevant error messages to your question, it's hard(er) to help you without it.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear wrote this way too late at night. The first 2 parts of the code where there to catch any other versions that sometimes appear and am no longer sure if they even appear anymore. The reason for not having any error message is that I don't get one it just sits there doing nothing. The reason for the last selector is because when you right click and copy from the inspect elements and copy the selector that's what you get. hanks for your help.

Comment: @AGenovez could you share the website so I can try it? I'm a bit blind here, trying it out would be better.

Comment: its the checkout in newegg

Comment: It seems like a pay wall after you finish checkout. I don't think I can do that.

Comment: darn ok well thanks for the help anyways. I feel like I've tried every selector that can find for that one element and cant get it going.

Answer (score 0):

What I found you can do is find the element using `querySelector` and then use `setAttribute` to give the elemtent an id.
So something like

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const inputBox = document.querySelector(".form-text mask-cvv-4");
    inputBoxes.setAttribute('id', 'inputBox1');
  });
await page.type("#inputBox1", "yourText");
```

If the element has children then you'd just have to get the children from the element. If there is multiple elements with the class tag you can use `querySelectorAll` and loop through that list.